# Are there any functions that are computable but not curriable?

Tags: currying, turing-machines, category-theory

Sorry if I'm a bit lost.
I've recently started learning about different programming language paradigms and I found that all texts presuppose that all functions written in a programming language are curriable.
I haven't seen any proof of this and after looking for a while I found information about cartesian closed categories. My knowledge of mathematics is quite limited so I don't know if this is applied to, well, everything that can be done with a turing machine. My guess is that something like this is proven (or maybe it's obvious and my knowledge is too limited). Thank you in advance.

I tried to find some answers in Google but I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer this question without a context. Currying means that a function that takes a pair of argumenst is equivalent to a function of one argument that returns a function of the second argument. So, obviously, in programming languages in which functions are not first-class citizens, currying makes no sense, since you can't return a function. In functional languages, on the other hand, currying is built in from the get go. In lambda calculus where everything is a function, the pair itself is defined as a function returning a function.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question then. Can lambda calculus produce an statement that isn't curriable?

Comment: I was abke to find the solution thanks to your pointing of lambda calculus. It was me missing fundamentals all along. Thank you for your response. In case anyone is curious here's the link. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Curry_theorem

Comment: I've made a mistake, it does NOT answer what I thought, it just implies that every function expressed in lambda calculus is curriable but it doesn't need to be computable. Basically the opposite of what i asked, which is still interesting.

Comment: According to Church-Turing thesis "a function is λ-computable if and only if it is Turing computable". 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis

Answer (score 0):

There is an isomorphism between curried and uncurried functions. For example in Haskell via

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y =  f (x, y)

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
uncurry f p =  f (fst p) (snd p)
```

such that

```
curry . uncurry = uncurry . curry = id
```

All properties of a function carry over via this isomorphism. In particular, if function `f` is (non)computable so is `curry f` and vice versa.

Note, whether a particular programming language is able to express the idea of currying is a different question. For example in pure lambda calculus there are only curried functions and no syntax for uncurried ones. Languages without support for higher order functions (e.g. the C language) make it hard (if not impossible) to write curried functions.